# AttributeError: dict object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I can't use my predict method when assigning my random forest regression model to user input in flask. It give me this error:

```
AttributeError: dict object has no attribute 'predict'
```

This is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import jsonify
import requests
import pickle
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open('random_forest_regression_model.pkl', 'rb'))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def Home():
    return render_template('index.html')


standard_to = StandardScaler()


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])


def predict():
    Fuel_Type_Diesel = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':

        Year = int(request.form['Year'])
        Present_Price = float(request.form['Present_Price'])
        Kms_Driven = int(request.form['Kms_Driven'])
        Kms_Driven2 = np.log(Kms_Driven)
        Owner = int(request.form['Owner'])
        Fuel_Type_Petrol = request.form['Fuel_Type_Petrol']

        if Fuel_Type_Petrol == 'Petrol':
            Fuel_Type_Petrol = 1
            Fuel_Type_Diesel = 0

        else:
            Fuel_Type_Petrol = 0
            Fuel_Type_Diesel = 1

        Year = 2020 - Year
        Seller_Type_Individual = request.form['Seller_Type_Individual']

        if Seller_Type_Individual == 'Individual':
            Seller_Type_Individual = 1


        else:
            Seller_Type_Individual = 0

        Transmission_Mannual = request.form['Transmission_Mannual']

        if Transmission_Mannual == 'Mannual':
            Transmission_Mannual = 1


        else:
            Transmission_Mannual = 0

        prediction = model.predict([[Present_Price, Kms_Driven2, Owner, Year, Fuel_Type_Diesel, Fuel_Type_Petrol,
                                     Seller_Type_Individual, Transmission_Mannual]])
        output = round(prediction[0], 2)

        if output < 0:
            return render_template('index.html', prediction_text="Sorry you cannot sell this car")

        else:
            return render_template('index.html', prediction_text="You Can Sell The Car at {}".format(output))

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

My HTML code (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="color:red">
        <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
            <h2>Predictive analysis</h2>
            <h3>Year</h3>
            <input id="first" name="Year" type="number ">
            <h3>What is the Showroom Price?(In lakhs)</h3><br><input id="second" name="Present_Price" required="required">
            <h3>How Many Kilometers Drived?</h3><input id="third" name="Kms_Driven" required="required">
            <h3>How much owners previously had the car(0 or 1 or 3) ?</h3><br><input id="fourth" name="Owner" required="required">
            <h3>What Is the Fuel type?</h3><br><select name="Fuel_Type_Petrol" id="fuel" required="required">
                <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
                <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                <option value="Diesel">CNG</option>
            </select>
            <h3>Are you A Dealer or Individual</h3><br><select name="Seller_Type_Individual" id="resea" required="required">
                <option value="Dealer">Dealer</option>
                <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
            </select>
            <h3>Transmission type</h3><br><select name="Transmission_Mannual" id="research" required="required">
                <option value="Mannual">Manual Car</option>
                <option value="Automatic">Automatic Car</option>
            </select>
            <br><br><button id="sub" type="submit ">Calculate Selling Price</button>
            <br>




        </form>



        <br><br><h3>{{ prediction_text }}<h3>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Error

```
line 70, in predict
prediction = model.predict([[Present_Price, Kms_Driven2, Owner, Year, Fuel_Type_Diesel, Fuel_Type_Petrol,
AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'predict'
```

**Line 70**

```
prediction = model.predict([[Present_Price, Kms_Driven2, Owner, Year, 
             Fuel_Type_Diesel, Fuel_Type_Petrol,Seller_Type_Individual, 
             Transmission_Mannual]])
```

Comment: It would help people help you if you pointed out line 70 or provided a [mre]

Comment: Please try to provide a **minimal** reproducible example; try to read your pickle file and then run `predict` - what happens? The rest of the (wall of) code here is actually irrelevant, and SO does **not** work by simply throwing all our code here as-is.

Comment: What type of object is `model`? Is it possible that you're expecting a scikit fitted estimator but instead you're loading a dictionary? If so, the problem is with the contents of `random_forest_regression_model.pkl` and not with the code. Maybe you should revise how that file was created.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the object saved in the file `random_forest_regression_model.pkl` is a dictionary. The data in that file seems to be wrong. You can try confirming that by printing `type(model)` after the line at the beginning where you load it using pickle.

You should create an object of the type that you actually want `model` to be and save it in that file. Then try running again.